# Feedback on different backends for GWT

Tags: java, python, gwt, architecture, web-frameworks

I have to re-design an existing application which uses Pylons (Python) on the backend and GWT on the frontend.
In the course of this re-design I can also change the backend system.
I tried to read up on the advantages and disadvantages of various backend systems (Java, Python, etc) but I would be thankful for some feedback from the community.

### Existing application:

The existing application was developed with GWT 1.5 (runs now on 2.1) and is a multi-host-page setup.
The Pylons MVC framework defines a set of controllers/host pages in which GWT widgets are embedded ("classical website").

Data is stored in a MySQL database and accessed by the backend with SQLAlchemy/Elixir. Server/client communication is done with RequestBuilder (JSON).

The application is not a typical business like application with complex CRUD functionality (transactions, locking, etc) or sophisticated permission system (tough a simple ACL is required).

The application is used for visualization (charts, tables) of scientific data. The client interface is primarily used to display data in read-only mode. There might be some CRUD functionality but it's not the main aspect of the app.
Only a subset of the scientific data is going to be transfered to the client interface but this subset is generated out of large datasets.
The existing backend uses numpy/scipy to read data from db/files, create matrices and filter them.
The numbers of users accessing or using the app is relatively small, but the burden on the backend for each user/request is pretty high because it has to read and filter large datasets.

### Requirements for the new system:

I want to move away from the multi-host-page setup to the MVP architecture (one single host page).
So the backend only serves one host page and acts as data source for AJAX calls.
Data will be still stored in a relational database (PostgreSQL instead of MySQL).
There will be a simple ACL (defines who can see what kind of data) and maybe some CRUD functionality (but it's not a priority).
The size of the datasets is going to increase, so the burden on the backend is probably going to be higher. There won't be many concurrent requests but the few ones have to be handled by the backend quickly. Hardware (RAM and CPU) for the backend server is not an issue.

### Possible backend solutions:

**Python (SQLAlchemy, Pylons or Django):**

**Advantages:**

- Rapid prototyping.
- Re-Use of parts of the existing application
- Numpy/Scipy for handling large datasets.

**Disadvantages:**

- Weakly typed language -> debugging can be painful
- Server/Client communication (JSON parsing or using 3rd party libraries).
- Python GIL -> scaling with concurrent requests ?
- Server language (python) <> client language (java)

---

**Java (Hibernate/JPA, Spring, etc)**

**Advantages:**

- One language for both client and server (Java)
- "Easier" to debug.
- Server/Client communication (RequestFactory, RPC) easer to implement.
- Performance, multi-threading, etc
- Object graph can be transfered (RequestFactory).
- CRUD "easy" to implement
- Multitear architecture (features)

**Disadvantages:**

- Multitear architecture (complexity,requires a lot of configuration)
- Handling of arrays/matrices (not sure if there is a pendant to numpy/scipy in java).
- Not all features of the Java web application layers/frameworks used (overkill?).

I didn't mention any other backend systems (RoR, etc) because I think these two systems are the most viable ones for my use case. 
To be honest I am not new to Java but relatively new to Java web application frameworks. I know my way around Pylons though in the new setup not much of the Pylons features (MVC, templates) will be used because it probably only serves as AJAX backend.

If I go with a Java backend I have to decide whether to do a RESTful service (and clearly separate client from server) or use RequestFactory (tighter coupling). There is no specific requirement for "RESTfulness". In case of a Python backend I would probably go with a RESTful backend (as I have to take care of client/server communication anyways).

Although mainly scientific data is going to be displayed (not part of any Domain Object Graph) also related metadata is going to be displayed on the client (this would favor RequestFactory).
In case of python I can re-use code which was used for loading and filtering of the scientific data.
In case of Java I would have to re-implement this part.

Both backend-systems have its advantages and disadvantages. 
I would be thankful for any further feedback.
Maybe somebody has experience with both backend and/or with that use case.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same dilemma in the past. 
I was involved in designing and building a system that had a GWT frontend and Java (Spring, Hibernate) backend. Some of our other (related) systems were built in Python and Ruby, so the expertise was there, and a question just like yours came up.

We decided on Java mainly so we could use a single language for the entire stack. Since the same people worked on both the client and server side, working in a single language reduced the need to context-switch when moving from client to server code (e.g. when debugging). In hindsight I feel that we were proven right and that that was a good decision.

We used RPC, which as you mentioned yourself definitely eased the implementation of c/s communication. I can't say that I liked it much though. REST + JSON feels more right, and at the very least creates better decoupling between server and client. I guess you'll have to decide based on whether you expect you might need to re-implement either client or server independently in the future. If that's unlikely, I'd go with the KISS principle and thus with RPC which keeps it simple in this specific case.

Regarding the disadvantages for Java that you mention, I tend to agree on the principle (I prefer RoR myself), but not on the details. The multitier and configuration architecture isn't really a problem IMO - Spring and Hibernate are simple enough nowadays. IMO the advantage of using Java across client and server in this project trumps the relative ease of using python, plus you'll be introducing complexities in the interface (i.e. by doing REST vs the native RPC).

I can't comment on Numpy/Scipy and any Java alternatives. I've no experience there.